# Postgres SQL - Key is not present in table, but it is

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert values into a table called dummy from a csv file, in the table dummy I have a value ProductID which references ProductID from another table called product. An error happens though when it tries to copy off the first line of the csv file, it says the Key (productid)=(31) is not present in the table product.

This is false as 31 is present in that table under the productid column:   [image]

The csv file: [image]

Both data types for productID were declared as integers.

Here is the code:

```
     CREATE TABLE Product (
 VolumePerTon real,
 Name varchar(30) ,
 ValuePerTon real,
 ProductID integer ,
 PRIMARY KEY (ProductID) 
)





     CREATE TABLE Dummy (
   BatchID integer ,
      ProductID integer REFERENCES Product(ProductID), 
   ExtractionOrManufacturingDate varchar(30) ,
   OriginalFrom integer REFERENCES Planet(PlanetID)
   );
  \copy Dummy from './data/Batches.csv' with csv header;
```

here are my list of tables: [image]

When I do \dn, i get 1 row which says: public | username

When I do show search_path i get:  "$user", public

Product is a parent table and has 0 bytes in size for some reason

Comment: kmfv, are you sure it's both, `mysql` as well as `postgresql`?

Comment: Please only tag the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Please show the create statement for the dummy table and the code you are using to import the csv

Comment: I just updated it to include the code

Comment: The DETAIL says,  Key (productid)=(31) is not present in table "product", but it is.

Comment: The error is pretty specific `Key (productid)=(31) is not present in table "product"` and I would say correct. Since you do  show a `productid` of 31 in a `product` table I'm going to say you have more then one `product` table and the `search_path` is finding the wrong one when you do the `\copy`. FYI, naming a table `Dummy` without double quoting the name is going to lower case it to `dummy` so you might as well start with that.

Comment: I just added my list of tables, I only have one product table.

Comment: Try creating a dummy2 table without the foreign keys and import the csv file into it. Then see what values you get in dummy2.

Comment: In `psql` do: 1) `\dn` 2) `show search_path`. Add results to question. **Do Not** use images, copy and paste the text from the console.

Comment: I just added it to the question, i tried creating a 2nd dummy table without the references and i still get the same error

Comment: Also, Product is a parent table and has 0 bytes in size for some reason

Comment: Define `parent`? Is that parent in a `INHERIT` or a `PARTITION`? Also include complete definition of how `product` and it's child tables where created. Add answers as update to question.  FYI, this was information that should have been provided from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are making a trivial error, like looking at the wrong `product` table, that would mean that 31 is in the table, but not in the index, which in turn would mean that you are suffering from index corruption.

Run

```
REINDEX TABLE product;
```

and try again.

Another possible explanation (and based on your comment, probably the correct one) is that `product` has inheritance children. In that case, `SELECT` will return values from those child tables as well, but [you cannot refer to those entries in a foreign key relationship](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS):

> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.

In that case you will have to do without a foreign key.

Comment: I tried this and i still get the same error

Comment: Also, Product is a parent table and has 0 bytes in size for some reason

Comment: You might have mentioned that right away.

Comment: What's a way that i can insert values into the table without a foreign key ?

Comment: I don't understand that question. You insert just like before. I am not saying that you should remove the foreign key *column*, only that you'll have to live without the guarantees of a foreign key *constraint*.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
\dt+
```

to check the size of the table.
If "product" table is a "parent" table, then check out [this](https://raghavt.blog/size-of-partition-table-in-postgresql-9-0/) for more info about sizing.

Comment: yes product is a parent table